# Trying to make a point to point calculator. Unsupported operand types?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, math, operand

Im trying to make a program which calculates the distance between two user inputted points. How can I fix this so that it works? So far I have this

```
import math  

p1 = [int(input("PLease enter point 1x\n")), (input("Please enter point    1y\n"))]
p2 = [int(input("PLease enter point 2x\n")), (input("Please enter point 2y\n"))] 
distance = math.sqrt( ((p1[0]-p2[0])**2)+((p1[1]-p2[1])**2) )  

print(distance)
```

The error that it spits out at me is: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Am I going about this in the right way at all?

Comment: You didn't cast your second set of inputs to `int`

Comment: wow am I dumb. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much what @idjaw said. You are missing the cast to int in second set.
    import math

```
p1 = [int(input("PLease enter point 1x\n")), int(input("Please enter point    1y\n"))]
p2 = [int(input("PLease enter point 2x\n")), int(input("Please enter point 2y\n"))] 
distance = math.sqrt( ((p1[0]-p2[0])**2)+((p1[1]-p2[1])**2) )  

print(distance)
```

Comment: wow am I dumb. thanks